# Excel array formula to sum for criteria then sort

Tags: excel, array-formulas

Looking for an excel array formula to sum "weight" for each "code" and sort "code"s in order of weight.

```
    |   A   |    B   |   C   |   D   |    E    |
 |1 |  Code | Weight |       |  Code |TotWeight|
 |2 |  444  |   30   |       |  444  |   50    |
 |3 |  333  |   10   |       |  222  |   40    |    
 |4 |  222  |   10   |       |  333  |   40    |
 |5 |  444  |   10   |       |  555  |   20    |        
 |6 |  444  |   10   |
 |7 |  222  |   30   |
 |8 |  333  |   20   |
 |9 |  555  |   20   |
 |10|  333  |   10   |
```

Cols A and B are inputs, D and E are outputs.

Answer (score 1):

While this may ultimately be possible with a convoluted and calculation-intensive array formula, for all intents and purposes you are really trying to accomplish a database SELECT statement with an aggregate SUM, GROUP BY and ORDER BY clauses. Something like,

```
SELECT code, weight FROM
 (SELECT cw.code, Sum(cw.weight) AS weight
  FROM tblCodeWeights AS cw
  GROUP BY cw.code)
ORDER BY weight DESC, code;
```

I would suggest a VBA sub procedure utilizing ADODB.Connection to the worksheet that can produce the results you are trying to achieve. The following code is verbose and could likely be trimmed down a little but every facet of the operation is handled and should be self-explanatory or easily researchable.

```
Option Explicit

Sub sortedFilteredSums()
    Dim cnx As Object, rs As Object
    Dim sWS1 As String, sWB As String, sCNX As String, sSQL As String
    Dim ws1TBLaddr As String

    With Worksheets("Sheet8")
        ws1TBLaddr = .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Address(0, 0)
        sWS1 = Worksheets("Sheet8").Name
    End With

    sWB = ThisWorkbook.FullName
    sCNX = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & sWB _
        & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"
    Debug.Print sCNX

    Set cnx = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    cnx.Open sCNX

    sSQL = "SELECT [code], [weight] FROM ("
    sSQL = sSQL & " SELECT cw.[code], SUM(cw.[weight]) AS [weight]"
    sSQL = sSQL & " FROM [" & sWS1 & "$" & ws1TBLaddr & "] cw"
    sSQL = sSQL & " GROUP BY cw.code"
    sSQL = sSQL & ") ORDER BY [weight] DESC, [code]"

    Debug.Print sSQL
    'SELECT code, weight FROM
    ' (SELECT cw.code, Sum(cw.weight) AS weight
    '  FROM tblCodeWeights AS cw
    '  GROUP BY cw.code)
    'ORDER BY weight DESC, code;

    rs.Open sSQL, cnx

    With Worksheets("Sheet8")
        .Range("D1").Resize(1, 2) = Array("code", "totweight")
        .Range("D2").CopyFromRecordset rs
    End With

    rs.Close: Set rs = Nothing
    cnx.Close: Set cnx = Nothing

End Sub
```

Please note that this cannot be performed on a workbook that has not been saved; e.g. not on a new untitled workbook. Your results should be similar to the following.

[image: sum_group_order]

The test workbook used for this example is temporarily available from:

[ADO Select Sum Group By.xlsb](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/100009401/ADO%20Select%20Sum%20Group%20By.xlsb)

Comment: Thank you. I'm after a solution that doesn't use any VBA.

Answer (score 1):

As explained by @Jeeped this request is quite complex.
However it can be achieved with formulas with the help of a working column.

Assuming your data is located at `A1:B11`

Title Column `C` as `Total.Weight` and enter this formula in `C2:C11`:

`=IF(COUNTIF($A$1:$A2,$A2)>1,"",
SUMIF($A$1:$A$11,$A2,$B$1:$B$11))`

Then with the expected results located at `F2:G11`enter these formulas:

In `F2:F11`: `=IF(EXACT($G2,""),"",INDEX($A$1:$A$11,MATCH($G2,$C$1:$C$11,0)))`

In `G2:G11`: `=IFERROR(LARGE($C$1:$C$11,COUNTA($F$1:$F1)),"")`

[image: Fig.1]
*Fig.1*

The formulas above work for the data provided in the question.

However if there are Codes with same Total Weight then an additional working column is required.

Title column `D` as `Rank` and enter this formula to rank the Total Weight (see Fig.2):

in `D2:D11`:

`=IFERROR(RANK.EQ($C2,$C$2:$C$11, 0)
+COUNTIF($D$1:$D1,RANK.EQ($C2,$C$2:$C$11, 0)),"")`

And the formulas at `F2:G11` should be these:

In `F2:F11`: `=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$11,MATCH(COUNTA($F$1:$F1),$D$1:$D$11,0)),"")`

In `G2:G11`: `=IF(EXACT($F2,""),"",SUMIF($A$1:$A$11,$F2,$B$1:$B$11))`

[image]
*Fig.2*